How can I create ANDROID_HOME environment with my pydroid 3
I tried to run this program it keep asking for ANDROID_HOME environment.
from uiautomator import device as d
import time

def record_touch_events():
    with open("touch_events.txt", "w") as f:
        while True:
            event = d.device.wait.update()
            if event["eventType"] == "k":
                f.write(event["key"])
                f.write('\n')
            elif event["eventType"] == "e":
                break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    record_touch_events()

enter image description here
Here is the error I got

Please [edit] your question and include the error message as text, not image. See [ask].

@Robert automation of UI python libraries doesn't work on Android/IOS . The application is just a mimic of actual shell with a very few available commands.

Is this helping?
